# Error in segue two view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have my storyboard like in this picture:
[image]

It works before I change in the right view the class from de default UIViewController to my MenuViewController. If I change it, when I push the button it turns black on emulator.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess:

remove the `- (void)loadView` implementation from your code. You don't need that for view controllers that are created from a nib file (or a storyboard).

Most likely it is there because of a bug in the new Xcode templates.

EDIT: This bug is fixed in Xcode 4.3.2. The template does no longer contain `- (void)loadView`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once and I couldn't figure out why. In the end I deleted the ViewController.h and .m  and created new ones and it worked.
Originally I may have created class files as UIView an tried changing them to UIViewController. Creating new ones as UIViewController worked.